# Getting the total price of products in Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my first time asking a question because I've tried everything that I've researched from this website for hours but nothing seems to work. I'm trying to get the total price of my cart but every time the state changes it constantly adds and I just want the total to stay as it is when I'm changing pages. Even clicking a delete button from my cart page, refreshes  the function and it adds another value to the total. Thank you so much if someone could help me

Here's the code that I've tried

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: white,
    body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection("cart")
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(user.uid)
            .collection("cart")
            .get()
            .then((querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
            total += result.data()['price'];
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all why do you send a request inside builder again? There is already a variable called "snapshot". You can get data with snapshot.data.docs.

Secondly, you are trying to increase total value every time without reset. If you set total variable to 0 before adding the prices probably it will solve your problem.

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: white,
     body: StreamBuilder(
       stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection("cart")
          .snapshots(),
      builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
         if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
         } else {
            total = 0;
            snapshot.data.docs.forEach((result) {
               total += result.data()['price'];
            });
            return WidgetYouWantToUse();
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining that to me, I've just studied this language 3 days ago and the reason why I iterate another snapshot because the ['price'] is not being defined and someone found a solution for that by adding 'as dynamic' as shown here total += (result.data() as dynamic)['price'];

I've managed to work it out after understanding it for quite a while, I'm a slow learner. Thank you soooo sooo much for helping me! You also taught me that I'm not resetting things. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

First of all, you are using a `StreamBuilder` and even though you provide a `Stream`, you call the stream again at `builder` method, you can can access the value of the `Stream` through the `snapshot`. Moreover, your builder returns no `Widget` but just iterates through the items of the `Stream`, to calculate I guess the total price. Instead, you can change the `builder` method to something like this

```dart
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: white,
    body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection("cart")
          .snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
       var data = snapshot.data;
       var totalCartPrice = data.fold(0,(prev, element)=>prev['price']+element['price']);
       return Text(totalCartPrice);
        });
```

Instead of using `fold` method you can iterate the `data` and do the calculations by hand. But I find it more elegant.

There was no reason in calling `setState` aswell, the `StreamBuilder` fires changes if anything changes in the Firestore document.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me but I can't seem to find the fold method work, I'm a beginner so I only understand so much. I've managed to solve my problem by your explanation that I'm not returning a widget. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that total value keeps on increasing whenever stream builder is called. Also, you do not need to listen to stream and still call get(). The stream returns similar value to the get.

Change your code to this

```
return Scaffold(
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection("cart")
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Something went wrong');
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        return CircularProgressIndicator();

      // NB: I set the value of total = 0; so that anytime the stream
      // builder is called, total starts from 0.
      total = 0;
      snapshot.data.docs.forEach((result) {
        total += result.data()['price'];
      });
      print(total);
      print('done');
      return Text('done');
    },
  ),
);
```

On the other hand, you can still call this function using futureBuilder.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .collection("cart")
        .get(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Something went wrong');
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        return CircularProgressIndicator();

      total = 0;
      snapshot.data.docs.forEach((result) {
        total += result.data()['price'];
      });
      print(total);
      print('done');
      return Text('done');
    },
  ),
);
```

The difference between stream and future builder is that future builder is only called once. Stream builder is called whenever the data changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying the use of future builder and stream builder to me! It will help me a lot in the future thank you so much!!!